# Not able to get my application logs using "cf logs my-cool-app" command (CF version 6.11)

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I am trying view logs of my running application on Bluemix using :  "cf logs my-cool-app" command (CF version 6.11) .

If fails with :

```
FAILED
Loggregator endpoint missing from config file
```

Anyone seen this issue?

Comment: Are you pointed to eu-gb.bluemix.net or ng.bluemix.net?

Comment: API endpoint: https://api.ng.bluemix.net (API version: 2.19.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to stem from the use of the 6.11 codebase for CF CLI and the current version of CloudFoundry that Bluemix is running. Good news is that an upcoming upgrade will alleviate the problem. We're investigating potential workarounds.

This is just an issue with the CF CLI version 6.11.

Comment: how do I downgrade CF in the context of the BX cli? This bug reallllly sucks :(