# Not able to get my application logs using "cf logs my-cool-app" command (CF version 6.27)

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud-tools

I see an [issue just like this from a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707417/not-able-to-get-my-application-logs-using-cf-logs-my-cool-app-command-cf-vers), but I am facing the same problem.

I am using `cf version 6.27.0+d26b32dcc.2017-06-08` and `bx version 0.5.4+ae22935-2017-05-18T06:24:28+00:00`

When I issue `bx app logs <myappname>`, I get this error `Loggregator endpoint missing from config file`
If I issue `cf logs <myappname>`, it works like a charm.

Can anyone provide guidance on this? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bx app logs` is using embedded cf cli, while that embedded version cf cli is too old.

A workaround is to copy the cf cli binary to directory "/usr/local/Bluemix/bin/cfcli"

Comment: Thanks, this also fixed my issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630333/bx-cf-logs-gives-error-dialing-traffic-controller-server-when-switching-region) If you add your answer there I can accept it. I did `cd /usr/local/Bluemix/bin/cfcli; sudo cp cf cf.bkp; sudo ln -s /usr/bin/cf cf`

Comment: @amadain the linking did not work for me, bx command told me that my bluemix cli env is not configured properly. So I did the following and it worked:
`cd /usr/local/Bluemix/bin/cfcli`
`sudo mv ./cf cf.backup` <-- backup current bluemix cf
`which cf` <-- to get where is cf installed in my system
`sudo cp /usr/local/bin/cf cf`

Then my `bx app logs <app name>` worked. 
Thank you both

Comment: @bluetea that's interesting, it just worked for me - on RedHat.  Remember the way to say thank you on SO is to accept user8185073's answer ;-).

Comment: @amadain I am on OSX so that could be the difference (I should have mentioned that in my original post).

Answer (score 0):

by the way, the coming release v0.5.5 will fix this issue