# Bluemix CF App Loggregator endpoint missing from config file

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to tail the logs of an app I've deployed in Bluemix. Each time I deploy via `bx app push [app-name]` I get the following error (but deployment is still successful):

```
Warning: error tailing logs
Loggregator endpoint missing from config file
```

Attempting to tail the logs yields:

```
$ bx app logs [app-name]
Invoking 'cf logs [app-name]'...

FAILED
Loggregator endpoint missing from config file
```

This is a Node.js app, is there something I need to define in my `package.json`? Everything I've read in the [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/monitor_log/logging/cfapps/logging_cf_apps.html#logging_bluemix_cf_apps) makes it seem like this should just work automatically:

> The Loggregator automatically picks up STDOUT and STDERR data.

Version info:

```
$ bx -v
bx version 0.5.4+ae22935-2017-05-18T06:24:28+00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hear the Bluemix `bx` CLI bundles an older cf CLI version.
The cf CLI 6.24.0 stopped supporting the deprecated "loggregator" endpoint in favor for the doppler endpoint.
So when you do a `cf api` or `cf login` with cf CLI >=6.24.0, the loggregator endpoint will not be added to the config file, causing `bx` to fail collecting logs. This would cause the warning you see with `bx app push`, `bx app start` (when staging) and `bx app restage`, as well as `bx app logs` to fail.
Work-around until `bx` is updated would be to either follow the steps suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44639332/1227328, or just to not mix the use of `bx` with any cf CLI version >=6.24.0, and set the API endpoint again one more time to have the (older) CLI save the "loggregator" endpoint in its local config file.